# Selenium for docker issue

Tags: selenium, docker, selenium-chromedriver, specflow, selenium-grid

I have recently set up a selenium grid running in Docker. My current setup has the hub running in Docker on its own VM. I have another docker instance with 4 chrome nodes running on another VM. Both machines are running Docker toolbox for Windows (2012 Servers). I am able to get the hub and nodes to communicate properly but when I run my test suite all of my tests fail. I always get this error

```
Session [83a2a83d-9c59-45a7-a8ad-5a65e267fa9c] was terminated due to CLIENT_GONE
```

Here is the docker command I use to create the hub

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -e JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx512m --name selenium-hub selenium/hub:3.0.1-aluminum
```

Here is the node command

```
docker run -d -p 5555:5555 -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm -e JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx512m -e SE_OPTS="-host IP -port 5555" -e HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=IP -e HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444 --name Node1 selenium/node-chrome:3.0.1-aluminum
```

I use Specflow+ to run my tests with it set to run 4 test threads at a time.

```
 <Environment platform="x64" testThreadIsolation="Process"/>
 <Execution stopAfterFailures="0" retryFor="None" testThreadCount="4" testSchedulingMode="Adaptive"/>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

**

### UPDATE

**

Here is the code I use to connect to the grid:

```
 DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
        dc.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, new Platform(PlatformType.Linux));
        dc.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "chrome");
 driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http:IPADDR/wd/hub"), dc);
```

Comment: Could you show us from your code how you connect to the selenium grid?

Comment: Additionally, have a look at this example: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow.Plus.Examples/tree/master/SeleniumGridWebTest It uses the SpecFlow+Runner and Selenium Grid to run the test in parallel.

Comment: @AndreasWillich see the update for the code.

Comment: From the code it looks good. Could you have a networking problem between the grid and the nodes?

Comment: @AndreasWillich no the test are actually executing but it seems they only get to a certain point before i get that "Client_GONE" error. I also changed my srprofile to look similar to the example one and i receive a  "no such session error".

Comment: It seems that I can only have 4 nodes connected to the HUB and setting the test to run on 3 threads. I add anymore nodes I get the "client gone" error.